# Unable to send the proper id from the request in JSP

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I am implementing the edit functionality as follows:

Getting the result from the spring controller and populating the HTML table with EDIT and DELETE options.

Like for example
345   Transport          BUS          370KM       EDIT | DELETE

I have a div for edit options

```
<div id ='xx'>
   <form:form action="get/{id}"/>
    <form:input ... />
```

Once the user clicks on edit, simply it displays on the same page using java script function.

```
function edit(id){
// making the div visible
Using the ajax for div form submit
$.ajax(){
url:'xx'+id; // appending the id here
}
```

Sorry am not posting the exact code but syntactically its good. When I click on EDIT it sends the exact id and after submitting the form its working as expected.

Again If I press another row edit option still its retaining the same id( as per the first click)

Can you guys please help me out to fix this issue. When I click the EDIT for the first time it works pretty good but after pressing EDIT option again  its returning the same id and passing through the Ajax.

Thanks,
Pooja.

Comment: I think there are same ids for your rows ..right??

Comment: @BrijeshBhatt  No these IDs from database.

Comment: Provide the html and this edit function mentioned here.. i think the problem is because of the same ids ..in any case post the code ..